# Count deleted files with interactive rm (rm -i)

Tags: bash, rm, interactive

I want to count number of interactively removed files and directories:

```
for f in /tmp/mydir/* ; do
  rm -ir "$f"
done
```

How to do it in most concise/elegant way?

---

*Example:*

```
abc@def:/tmp/mydir$ tree
.
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
├── 4
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── B
│   ├── 1
│   └── 2
└── C

3 directories, 9 files
```

If all answers are **y** (yes), then I expect answer:

- **7** (count: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `A`, `B`, `C`) or:
- **10** (count: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `A/1`, `A/2`, `A/3`, `B/1`, `B/2`, `C`).

Both versions are welcome.

I know that I can count files/directories before and after running interactive `rm`, but this is not the case because in fact I iterate through files stored in text file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use:

```
rm -vri files | wc -l
```

will include dirs, too (i.e. the removal of `A`). This will work as `-v` will only send successful `removed ’file’` (or dir) output to `stdout`, while all others go to `stderr`.

In your example the output will be `12`, as there are 3 dirs and 9 files.